# What would "the 2021 school/fiscal year" refer to?

Tags: numbers, range-inclusion, convention

Generally students start the Nth grade in the fall of some calendar year Y and graduate that grade in the spring of some calendar year Y+1. Likewise if a fiscal year does not start on January 1 it would also start in a first calendar year and end in a second year.

So to avoid ambiguity one might do well to refer to "the 2021–2022 school year".

But am I correct that, if/when abbreviated this would become "the 2021 school year" (i.e. represented by the year when it started), and **not** "the 2022 school year" (i.e. *not* represented by the year when it ends)? Is the convention for fiscal years the same as for school years?

[mods: I was hoping to tag this "calendar" which seems like a potentially useful tag here, but didn't have enough rep….]

Comment: I work for a company that has a fiscal year that doesn't start on Jan 1 and the shortest we ever abbreviate it is "2021/22" (spoken as "twenty-twenty-one, twenty-two").

Comment: My company works with a bunch of different schools, and the answer is basically "yes". I.e. pick a standard, any standard, and some school out there uses it, meaning that "the 2021 school year" is meaningless unless you know which school you're talking about.

Comment: In Australia, "the 2021 school year" would make perfect sense, as the school year there generally falls within a single calendar year (starting in January or February and ending in December).

Comment: @CanadianYankee - when speaking I often say 'the twenty one twenty two finance year' for the period 1 April 2021 to 31 March 2022. If it is abundantly clear that we are talking about the finance year I'll leave out the last two words. When writing I could use a hyphen e.g. 2021-22 but I prefer 2021-2022.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like, at least for fiscal years, this may vary from country to country. [or perhaps from language to language in which case my question regarding the English usage would still stand!]

To quote the [current](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fiscal_year&oldid=1046169921) Wikipedia article for "Fiscal year":

> In some countries, the fiscal year is denoted by the calendar year in which it begins and so in India, for instance, spending incurred in March 2022 would be part of the fiscal year 2021, operating on a fiscal calendar of April–March. In other countries, the fiscal year is denoted by the calendar year in which it ends and so in the United States, federal government spending incurred on 14 November 2021 would belong to fiscal year 2022, which operates on a fiscal calendar of October–September.

I.e. an example "2021–22" fiscal year might be shortened to "FY21" in India but "FY22" in the United States. Thus if using the **end** year is common convention in at least one of the American Englishes, my assumption that "SY21" refers to "school year 2021–22" would be wrong — "SY21" would instead refer to "school year 2020–21"!

**UPDATE**: I wonder if perhaps the India/USA distinction could be viewed a different way!? That is, the examples compare an April–March to an October–September range. The majority of time between April 2021 and March 2022 would happen in 2021. The majority of time between October 2021 and September 2022 would happen in 2022. Hmm… so if the fiscal year of India went from December to December would they still refer to it by the start year? Or if that of the United States went from February to February would they still refer to it by the end year? What then for a *school* year which tends to be a bit more balanced between its two calendar years? My answer is now more questions

Answer (score 2):

In the US, the 2022 school year is the one that starts in 2021 and ends in 2022 (when the class of 2022 graduates). And fiscal year 2022 (FY22) is the same period, at least if you're an educational institution. The year officially starts July 1, though students start in late August or early September and end in June.

It is my job to know stuff like this. Nevertheless, I found some other examples from the internet at large.

- > To jumpstart the 2022 school year, the [USV](https://facebook.com/USVenture/videos/to-jumpstart-the-2022-school-year-the-usvschmidt-family-foundation-presented-sch/800576503942807/?refsrc=deprecated)/Schmidt Family Foundation presented scholarships to these eager students!
- > Welcome to the 2022 School year — [Carrie Jacobs Bond Elementary School](https://www.bondelementary.org/m/pages/index.jsp?uREC_ID=487385&type=d&termREC_ID=&pREC_ID=936539)
- > Are you an upcoming Senior for the 2022 school year? [PhotographyByChristy](https://photographybychristywv.com/senior-modelprogram-2022) is looking for Senior's from each High School for the class of 2022!

Still, you should prefer to write out 2021-2022 when possible.

Comment: For some schools, your answer is correct. For other schools, your answer is dead wrong.

Comment: American schools have the concept of a "class of 2025" which means people who graduate in the summer 2025, so everything is organised that way. Other institutions and other countries don't think the same way, particularly if nobody graduates. Always best to give both years.